# How can i make my search bar fit to the end of my container while being responsive?

Tags: html, css

In my website i have a container and a search bar to search items, the thing is my search bar only goes half way instead of to the end of the container. I tried adding width:19% in "container form" and it does work except when i shrink or stretch the screen it moves out of it. Can someone help me fix this issue?
[image: The search bar not going to the end]

This is my code:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(240, 239, 243);
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 375px;
  height: 520px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 30px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.container form {
  border: 1px solid rgb(82, 74, 235);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.container form input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <form>
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <input type="text" name="" id="search-item" placeholder="Search products" onkeyup="search()">
  </form>

  <div class="product-list" id="product-list">

    <div class="product">
      <img src="img/tshirt1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="p-details">
        <h2>Black Tshirt</h2>
        <h3>$25</h3>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your form does have a default width which is , excuse me if I'm wrong, `auto`. Setting the form width to `inherit` will give it the width of the parent section element and also give your search box a parent width to become the 100% width of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are improvements that could be made in addition to this, the one change I made – which resolved the problem – was the removal of `position: absolute` from the following declaration:

```
.container form {
  border: 1px solid rgb(82, 74, 235);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  /* comment out, or remove, the following
     line:
  position: absolute; */
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(240, 239, 243);
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 375px;
  height: 520px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 30px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.container form {
  border: 1px solid rgb(82, 74, 235);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  /* commented out this line:
  position: absolute;
  */
}

.container form input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- admittedly I also added this <link>, but that's
     purely because you were referencing font-awesome
     classes, and that irked me when font-awesome wasn't
     included. -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<section class="container">

  <form>
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <input type="text" name="" id="search-item" placeholder="Search products" onkeyup="search()">
  </form>

  <div class="product-list" id="product-list">

    <div class="product">
      <img src="img/tshirt1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="p-details">
        <h2>Black Tshirt</h2>
        <h3>$25</h3>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if i do this it does work but then if i scroll the search bar will also scroll up but i want it to stay in one place

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it by setting the form width to `inherit` so that it takes on the containing parent section element's width.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(240, 239, 243);
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 375px;
  height: 520px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 30px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.container form {
  border: 1px solid rgb(82, 74, 235);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.container form input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}

.myform{
  width:inherit;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <form class="myform">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    <input type="text" name="" id="search-item" placeholder="Search products" onkeyup="search()">
  </form>

  <div class="product-list" id="product-list">

    <div class="product">
      <img src="img/tshirt1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="p-details">
        <h2>Black Tshirt</h2>
        <h3>$25</h3>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @david-thomas' answer is probaby better since I overlooked the `position: absolute`. You really only want to use `absolute` positioning when you really really need to. my `inherit` fix would be more of a patch on top of it, without fixing the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it does work except it goes again a bit out of the container box

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the input width just by giving its width 375px which is exactly equal to container width..
Here is the updated code

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(240, 239, 243);
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 375px;
  height: 520px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 30px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.container form {
  border: 1px solid rgb(82, 74, 235);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.container form input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  **width: 375px;** 
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}

.search-item {
  padding:110px;
}
```